# Stripe Payment Element - Custom Business Details

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Please see partial screenshot of Bacs Direct Debit Mandate confirmation modal that is generated by Stripe Elements JS (Payment Element).

[image]

The business details are autogenerated as below:

```
Stripe, 7th Floor The Bower Warehouse
207-211 Old St, London EC1V 9NR
support@stripe.com
```

I need these to pull in the business details from my Stripe account, or to be able to updated these within the Javascript for this payment element.

Is this possible?

I have read through as much documentation as I can find and have tried adding in a business object as below but no change.

```
const paymentElement = this.elements.create('payment', {
    layout: {
        type: 'accordion',
        defaultCollapsed: false,
        radios: false,
        spacedAccordionItems: true
    },
    business: {
        name: 'MyBusinessName'
    },
    defaultValues: {
        billingDetails: billingDetails
    },
    paymentMethodOrder: ['bacs_debit', 'card']
});

paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this could be possible by upgrading to [Custom Branding](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/bacs-debit#custom-branding). Stripe’s support team might be able to help.